# How to resolve the orientation of ImagePicker control view in landscape mode and whole application in portrait mode?

Tags: ios6, uiimagepickercontroller, xcode4.5, uiinterfaceorientation

What I want is my whole application is in portrait mode only.

And it working fine in ios 6+. The only support required at now.

But the problem is I need to launch UIImagePickerViewController with image source type camera in only landscape mode.

What I tried till now is:

(1) I try to create one category for UIImagePickerController for orientation.

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return NO;
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft;
}
```

Like this. But the camera view is not proper aligned. It just follows the orientation of device with some +/- 90 angle but not what I required.

Even the button of the camera shown by camera view as camera control is also follows the camera view, ie. the view is rotated to 90 anti clock vise and stays to that way.

I use the below code to present the image picker view controller

```
[self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Is there any way to use the camera with proper alignment? or have to use other framework to work with it?